# Python 3.8 Logging Issue

Tags: python, logging

Has anyone ever seen this with logging?

`DEBUG:wc_to_db_logger:inactive not_applicable`

It occurs whenever I put a wc_to_db_logger.debug() in to my code, even if it is not executed.  Very strange I cannot find the error anywhere.

I have added a code snipp-it below.  Just placing the wc_to_db_logger.debug in the code under a function causes the issue.  It repeats the error 18 times.

```
            elif source == 'gs':
                try:
                    row_data = gs_worksheet_by_customer_id[self.customer_id]
                except KeyError:
                    continue

                value = row_data[source_name]
                value = convert_gs_to_db(data_type, value)

                if db_value != value:
                    wc_to_db_logger.debug('%s %s' % (db_value, value))
                    setattr(self, attribute_name, value)
```

Comment: Could you share a code snippet so we can have more context on this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Is that the entire output?

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to solve it by adding the following to my logger;
`wc_to_db_logger.propagate = False`

Apparently I need to learn more about the logger.  Wish me luck.

*** UPDATE ***

My fix did not work, it just disabled logging.  I will put up a code snippit.